# Entity Framework and LLBLGen

Tags: entity-framework-4, llblgen

I have a database, which has two tables. The Order table, and the Item table. The relationship is m:1.

I am using LLBLGen as the mapping tool to generate the source file.

I can see that the ItemID from the Item table is displayed in the Order entity from the designer of LLBLGen, which is correct.

However, when I try to call this generated source codes, the ItemID is not listed as a property of my Order class. Actually all my foreign key is gone.

How can I generate the foreign key as a property?

Answer (score 1):

It's a setting. Go to:
Project properties -> Output Setting values Tab -> EmitForeignKeyFields, check the checkbox. Ok -> regenerate code.

It's false by default.

Ps: if you post your question on our own support forums, you might get answers more quickly ;)